# How to add 'select one' to a spinner, which gets data after api call

Tags: android

I have a spinner which populates data after an API call. I need to add an item that says "select one" as a first item in spinner. This item should not be able to be selected. I tried several ways online, but not able to implement it in my code since the array is filled after the api call and couldn't figure out a correct way to add  "select one" item to that array.. Could anyone tell me how to do this in my code?

```
public void TEMPLATE_PARSE(JSONArray array) {
    TemplateArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    TemplateNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            ModelTemplate GetTemplateDataModel = new ModelTemplate(); 
            GetTemplateDataModel.setTemplateID(json.getInt("TemplateID"));
            GetTemplateDataModel.setTemplateText(json.getString("TemplateText"));
            TemplateArrayList.add(GetTemplateDataModel);
            TemplateNames.add(TemplateArrayList.get(i).getTemplateText().toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // Close for loop here

    if (array.length() != 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, simple_spinner_item, TemplateNames);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
        spinTemplate.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);            
        spinTemplate.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("ssssmIsSpinnerFirstCall",mIsSpinnerFirstCall.toString());
                if(!mIsSpinnerFirstCall) {
                    selectedTemplateID = TemplateArrayList.get(position).getTemplateID();
                    String selectedTemplateText = TemplateArrayList.get(position).getTemplateText();
                    editText.setText(selectedTemplateText);
                    saveInSp("selectedTemplateID", String.valueOf(selectedTemplateID));
                    templateSelected = true;

                }
                mIsSpinnerFirstCall = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `Select One` at position 0 to **TemplateNames** and then create adapter and set it to `Spinner`

```
TemplateNames.add(0, "Select One");
```

And then inside `onItemSelected`, check selected position and do whatever you want.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(position == 0)
        // Skip or show validation message if you want
    else {
        // Do your actual task here
         ...

         selectedTemplateID = TemplateArrayList.get(position - 1).getTemplateID();
         String selectedTemplateText = TemplateArrayList.get(position - 1).getTemplateText();

         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: When I did this, "Select One" is being added in the spinner. But when I'm selecting the last item in the spinner, it is showing error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4`

Comment: Because you access `TemplateArrayList ` with the same position where `Select One` is absent. That's why size mismatch

Comment: How? Do you check my code clearly? I already doing nothing when position == 0. Please check carefully and apply. Also please update your code with this implementation. so that I can check

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right. It's working as intended now. I was checking `if(!mIsSpinnerFirstCall)` condition inside the `else` condition you have mentioned by mistake.